Getting "no such file or directory" after switching asdf from homebrew to git install
I recently reinstalled asdf so that it would follow the recommended installation method of installing straight from git rather than homebrew. I am using oh-my-zsh on MacOS.
However, I started seeing some error messages whenever my terminal started up.
(eval):.:26: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/libexec/asdf.sh

This is bizarre to me as I could find nothing relating to this in my .zshrc or .zprofile.
When I run source ~/.zshrc, no errors are returned, but when I run omz reload I get the above error.
I did notice that asking homebrew for the prefix of asdf still does something:
brew --prefix asdf
/opt/homebrew/opt/asdf

Even though asdf is uninstalled from Homebrew
brew uninstall asdf
Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/asdf

Where could the no such file/directory error be coming from?

Can you try to remove the path manually?
rm -r /opt/homebrew/Cellar/asdf

rm -r /opt/homebrew/Cellar/asdf
rm: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/asdf: No such file or directory

are you using intel cpu?
